# How can I remove **only** the “Shut Down” option from the start menu?

Tags: windows, power, shutdown

I want to remove **only** the “shut down” option as I wrote in the title

Comment: What has your research shown?

Comment: I did not find anything

Comment: Please state why you would like to do that. Classic Shell allows you to customize the start menu..

Comment: Do you have the Pro version of Windows?

Comment: Twisty Impersonator Yes

Comment: Simlev because I do not want my sister to shutdown the computer, and I just don’t want it in there.

Comment: Removing the button is one thing, disallowing users to perform a shutdown is another business entirely. Your sister will still be able to turn off the computer in a number of ways.

Comment: Simlev I know… .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried via Policy ?

Take a look at: https://www.thewindowsclub.com/prevent-users-shutting-down-restarting-windows-computer

to restore the restart option simply create a link to:

```
shutdown.exe -f -r -t 1
```

More info can be found here: [How to remove shutdown option in start menu of Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/983797/how-to-remove-shutdown-option-in-start-menu-of-windows-10)