# What options on Windows 10 Pro v1809 can I use to prevent accidental shutdown?

Tags: windows-10

I need a Shutdown confirmation feature to safeguard my work computer from accidental shutdown while telecommuting.

### What I Tried

I found several options to add additional safeguards, but they don't seem to be available or work on Windows 10 Pro v1809.

1) **SuperUser (1016), [Implement a Shutdown Confirmation?](https://superuser.com/questions/1075582/implement-a-shutdown-confirmation/). The accepted answer is actually from a Windows 7 feature and instructs changing a setting in *Display Shutdown Event Tracker***:

`Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Display Shutdown Event Tracker`

This option is not available on my installation of Windows 10

2.) **[Another source of equal or older date](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/92vu8z/confirmation_before_shutdown/) offers two options using *Registry Editor***:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Reliability
```

(I only have `Terminal Services` and `Windows File Protection` DWORDS under Reliability)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Reliability
```

(only options are `DirtyShutdown`, `LastAliveStamp`, `TimeStampInterval`)

Unlike the example in the link, Reliability is a directory in my version:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Reliability\shutdown
```

The only option under `shutdown` is a single DWORD, `ReasonCode`. Is this a possible replacement for previous options?

3.) **Another post here asks to remove shutdown, [How to remove shutdown option in start menu of Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/983797/how-to-remove-shutdown-option-in-start-menu-of-windows-10)**:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Start\HideShutDown
```

Assuming I'm choosing the correct value to edit:

- Name: (Defult)
- Type: REG_SZ
- Data: 1

This didn't work after restart.

**Any suggestions or successes?**

Comment: "so it's a bit of Windows within Windows mirror vision sort of thing. ' - It is not clear what you mean by this statement.

Comment: Not important. I removed it. The login app gives me a full screen view of my desktop. So I'm starting my home computer with a Windows10 desktop, log into work, and see a full screen Windows10 desktop. I mistakenly thought I was on my local machine, and shutdown.