# Remove Power Options From Start Menu but Keep them in GINA Screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-server-2019, power-options

**Please do not close as a duplicate. [How to remove shutdown option in start menu of Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/983797/how-to-remove-shutdown-option-in-start-menu-of-windows-10) does not solve this problem. I want to see the power options on the GINA screen.**

The title basically sums it up.

I want to remove the Power Options in the Start Menu, just to prevent accidental shutdowns due to muscle memory.

I still want to be able to shutdown, without using a command prompt/desktop script, to shut down or restart.

So I want to keep the power options on the GINA (ctrl+alt+del) screen.

The `Remove and prevent access to the Shut Down, Restart..` group policy removes it from both. As far as I can tell the registry entries under `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Start\` also remove them from both.

Is there any way to remove from just Start?

Comment: Please reopen question. The question provided as a duplicate does not solve this issue. It removes the shutdown option from both the start menu and the GINA screen. I want to keep it on the GINA screen.